# How to iterate over S3 bucket objects and send messages to sqs

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have created a function to take a sqs message from a DLQ and place it in a S3 bucket. Now I want to create a function or way to redrive the message from S3. Currently I am trying to iterate over the objects find the new ones and then trigger their being sent to sqs and deleted from the bucket. Currently this is all I have.

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(bucket, event, context):


    client = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)

    for page in page_iterator:
        if page['KeyCount'] > 0:
            for item in page['Contents']:
                yield item


for i in lambda_handler(bucket='dlqbucket'):
    print (i)
```

Comment: Be careful about looping through a list of objects while deleting the objects. This might create a situation where `list_objects()` doesn't realise that the number of objects has changed between pagination calls. This could be avoided by retrieving the entire list of objects _before_ doing any deletions.

Comment: Your code should _not_ call `lambda_handler()` -- that is done automatically when the Lambda function is invoked. You should put your `for` loop within `lambda_handler()` and then move your iteration into a function (but see my comments above, so that code might need to change anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move the messages from your DLQ to the main queue, so that it can be processed again, you can use some scripts to do that without involving S3.

https://github.com/garryyao/replay-aws-dlq - This one works pretty well.

Once you install this, you need to run

```
replay-aws-dlq [dlq_url] [main_queue_url]
```

This will move all your DLQ messages to the main queue.